# TensorBoard 'double free or corruption' error

Tags: tensorboard

When I run [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard) (on an [AWS Bitfusion Ubuntu 14 TensorFlow AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01EYKBEQ0), version 2017.03; using a [P2 EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/p2/)) I regularly get:

```
*** Error in `/usr/bin/python3.4': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000000faf7a0 ***
```

Is this a known or common error? If so is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Did you tried [the solution presented on the project's issues tracker](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6968#issuecomment-279060156)?

Comment: @swapgs: `Unable to locate package libtcmalloc-minimal4`

Comment: [The package exists in Trusty](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libtcmalloc-minimal4). Did you ran `apt-get update` before trying to install it?